# Tumblr Login Script With Mechanize

Tags: ruby, authentication, mechanize, tumblr

I'm trying to make a ruby script using Mechanize, so I can login into Tumblr. I have the following script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

def get_page link
    agent = Mechanize.new
    page = agent.get(link)
end


def login email, pass
    login_page = get_page 'https://www.tumblr.com/login'
    dash = login_page.form_with(:action => 'https://www.tumblr.com/svc/account/register') do |f|
        f.fields[0] = email
        f.fields[1] = pass
    end.click_button
    dash
end
```

This code according to Mechanize website should work, but I always get this error:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mechanize-2.7.1/lib/mechanize/form.rb:312:in `block in save_hash_field_order': undefined method `node' for "email@email.com":String (NoMethodError)
```

Can anyone help me with this? Or if there already is a script for this can you point me to it? (I didn't found any)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you're doing but using fields[0] is a mess and a mistake.

In general:

```
form['email'] = email
form['password'] = password
next_page = form.submit form.button
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
f.fields[0] = email
f.fields[1] = pass
```

try

```
f.fields[0].value = email
f.fields[1].value = pass
```